# How to add images along with text using WYSIWYG text editor and save them togather into MySQL Database?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, textarea, wysiwyg, text-editor

I have used textarea to insert data into MySQL tables. But I am quite confused that how to add image and text together (like  WordPress Post) and save them together into MySQL database. I can add images and text to the MYSQL table separately. I want to use any WYSIWYG text editor. After that, I want to save it to the table. Please help me to sort out this problem.

Answer (score -1):

Why not just use Wordpress?  It is open source, and through plugins and themes/templates customization, it should be able to do anything you need.  No need to reinvent the wheel!

Comment: I am developing a custom PHP project where I am using WYSIWYG text editor. Therefore I can not use Wordpress.